# Windows switch languages alternative hotkey

Tags: windows-11

I know Win+Space hotkey. However Windows 11 shows the keyboard language selection even when pressing something else, but I don't know what or how to disable it.

It very frequently shows the selection dialog when playing FPS games or when programming. And I'm sure I'm not pressing Win or Space at that time, so it has to be some other shortcut

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check and change or disable language hotkey in Windows 11 as follows:

- Open the Settings app (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Click "Time & Language" on the left
- On the right click "Typing"
- On the right again, scroll down and click "Advanced keyboard settings"
- Click below on "Input language hot keys"
- In the "Text Services and Input Languages" dialog select
  "Advanced Key Settings"
- Select an entry and click "Change Key Sequence"
- Here you may change hotkey or select "Not assigned"
- Click OK to terminate.

Comment: I think this is it, thank you! Quite a hidden setting